# Linux/C: Writing command-line arguments to a text file as separate lines?

Tags: c, linux, file, command-line

I have made a simple program that reads input from command-line, saves it to a text file and then reads and prints the text file.

So I've been trying to modify it so that instead of saving the arguments as one big line of string, it would save each argument as an own line in the text file.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *filePointer;
 filePointer= fopen("number.txt","w");

 if(argc == 1)
 {
   printf("give at least one number!\n");
 }

 for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
 {
   fprintf(filePointer, argv[i]);
 } 
 fclose(filePointer);

 char readBuffer[100] = " ";

 filePointer= fopen("number.txt","r");
 while(fgets(readBuffer,sizeof(readBuffer),filePointer))
 {
   printf("\nNumber: %s\n", readBuffer);
 } 
 fclose(filePointer);
}
```

So when calling the program with two arguments: ./code 12345678 9101213

instead of this:

```
number: 12345678910111213
```

I would get this:

```
number: 12345678
number: 910111213
```

Comment: The second parameter of `fprintf` is a *format string.* Calling `./code '%s %s %s %s'`  most probably will crash your program.

Comment: Xing's suggestion actually worked!
So simple fix :) I have still lot to learn about C syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On saving line to file you should add „\n“ to argv[i]. Something like:

```
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
  fprintf(filePointer, "%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```